# how to paste specific columns of data with if statement vba

Tags: vba

I am currently doing a project where I am supposed to look at one column of data and then use an if statement to categorise it.

Which is if marks <= 10 then display at column A value column E
if marks <= 20 then display column A value at column F 
if marks less than or equal 30 then display column A value at column G etc. etc.

[column A is for names and column B is for student's marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnrvu.png)

```
   Sub CategorisePercentage()

     Dim finalRow As Integer
     Dim i As Integer

     finalRow = Sheets("NTB").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

     For i = 1 To finalRow
         If Cells(i, 2) <= 10 Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1)).Copy
            Range("E1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
         End If
     Next i

     Range("E2").Select

     End Sub
```

This is the codes I tried from watching a youtube tutorial but the codes is not working and I get the error "application-defined or object-defined error"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: A note that might help you debug your code, if you click in the left margin of your code you can set a breakpoint and then press F8 to step through your code 1 line at a time to find which line is causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling it its a range but only giving it one cell:

```
Range(Cells(i, 1)).Copy
```

I changed it to this and the code worked:

```
Cells(i, 1).Copy
```

This should fix the "application-defined or object-defined error".